# Angular. Make child 100% width of flex parent

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have an Angular component with a main flex div `main-container` and a child `box`. I want the child to be in the center of the parent and also to have 100% of parent's width. The snippet of code below, shows that my code is working, but in Angular, the width of `box` is 80px (made by the padding).

```css
.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 15px;
    background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.box {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a photo of how my Angular page looks like:

[image: Angular page with problem]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried after removing the `max-width` property. Also it would be better if you could share a Stackblitz with your problem.

Comment: I have tried after removing the max-width property and nothing is changed. I am creating now a Stackblitz page.

Comment: Stackblitz works fine... I guess my project has something wrong. I`ll check now

Comment: I would do margin: auto; width: 100%; instead of align-item and justify-content

Comment: New project seems to work fine now. Thank you for everything!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch `width: 100%` to `max-width: 100vw` in main-container, and use `flex: 1` in box container.

- `max-width` will prevent any horizontal scrollbar, keeping the container always visible.
- `flex: 1`: shortcut to `flex-grow: 1`, `flex-shrink: 1` and `flex-basis: 0px`, will force the box to fill all the remaining space inside the container.

```css
.main-container {
    max-width: 100vw; // <= try this
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 15px;
    background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #c850c0, #4158d0);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.box {
    flex: 1;  <= And this
    padding: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]